# How to find out if jquery.Callbacks collection is empty?

Tags: jquery

I use `$.Callbacks()` to store a list of callbacks. I would like to log if the list is empty before I call `fire` function on the list of callbacks.

Is it possible or not?

---

I did not find any method for this purpose in the [manual page](http://api.jquery.com/category/callbacks-object/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by the calling the `has` method and not passing anything:

```
var callbacks = $.Callbacks();
var empty = !callbacks.has();
```

This is undocumented, but I found the behavior by [examining the source](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.Callbacks):

```
// Check if a given callback is in the list.
// If no argument is given, return whether or not list has callbacks attached.
has: function (fn) {
    return fn ? jQuery.inArray(fn, list) > -1 : !!(list && list.length);
},
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7vf5b/

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully it is a bug in the documentation. I would rather not rely on an undocumented feature.

Comment: @MartyIX: You're welcome! Yeah, not sure if they'll remove it someday.